# Synonym of steepen?

Tags: synonyms

I normally use Thesaurus.com for all of my synonyming needs, but it doesn't seem to think "steepen" is a word. I was wondering if anyone knew of a synonym of the verb "to steepen".

Steepen: To become or cause to become steeper.

Comment: It might help to include the entire sentence you are trying to write because it appears that a synonym for _steepen_ will be obscure or awkward.

Comment: I doubt I've ever used *steepen* as a transitive verb. But surely you can check [more than one dictionary](http://www.onelook.com/?w=steepen&ls=a). As probablyme suggests, a sentence you want to use one in might help.

Comment: When we rotate the plane, we steepen its slope.  The bulldozer steepened the bank.

Answer (score 1):

As a transitive verb, I'd use "make steeper".

> I made the driveway steeper to avoid blocking the gutter.

As an intransitive verb, I'd use "get steeper" or "become steeper".

> The trail got steeper as we neared the peak of the mountain.

To me, *steepen* would sound strange when used as a transitive, and would sound "correct" but somewhat formal when used as an intransitive verb.